# Multiple Checkboxes with Select All

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I modified an existing [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUtJF/34/) to get a comprehensive solution for multiple checkboxes with select/unselect functionality. Now, **it counts how many checkboxes checked** and also **gives which the checkboxes checked**. It looks like it works fine but there are some points to fix and needs to improve it a bit more:

1. When you first check the option A and then click the "Select All" checkbox, the system does not work well.
2. The whole code looks like it's a bit long. I think we can shorten the code someway but I don't know how.
3. When we check all options manually, the firstgroup checkbox should automatically be checked or otherwise when any of the options are unchecked, the firstgroup checkbox should automatically unchecked. And accordingly, the div contents should change.

Thanks for any contribution.

```
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="firstgroup" /> Select All<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="order" id="first" /> A<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="order" id="second" /> B<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="order" id="third" /> C
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="form">Lorem ipsum</div>

    x = document.getElementById("result");
    y = document.getElementById("form");
    x.innerHTML = '';
    y.innerHTML = '';

$("#firstgroup").click(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox'].order");
    checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
});


$("input[type='checkbox'].order").change(function() {
    var check       = $("input[type='checkbox'].order:checked").length;
var tnocb = $("input[type='checkbox'].order").length;
    var classes = $("input[type='checkbox'].order:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(", ");

if(check > 0) {
    if(check == 1) {
        x.innerHTML = 'Checked Checkbox: ' + classes + '<br>Total number of checked checkbox: ' + check;
    } else if(check == tnocb) {
        x.innerHTML = 'all of them are checked';
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = 'Checked Checkboxes: ' + classes + '<br>Total number of checked checkboxes: ' + check;
    }
    y.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = '';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Well kinda unclear what you really want, but take a look http://jsfiddle.net/LUtJF/35/

Comment: Dear Carsten, thank you for your reply. It works well. Maybe, to improve the system one step further, we can add another functionality like when we check all the options manually, the system should check the firstgroup checkbox automatically. How can we do that? Now, it doesn't check the firstgroup checkbox automatically when all the options are checked manually.

Comment: Similarly, when we check the firstgroup checkbox and uncheck some of the options manually, the firstgroup checkbox remains checked. This is another item needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#firstgroup").click(function() {
  $('#form').text('');
  $('#result').text('');
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  if ($(".order:checked").length == 3) {
    $('#form').text('all of them are checked');
  }
});
$(".order").on('click', function() {
  var selectedItems = '';
  $('#result').text('');
  $('#form').text('');
  if ($(".order:checked").length == 3) {
    $('#form').text('all of them are checked');
    $("#firstgroup").prop('checked','checked');
  } else if ($(".order:checked").length > 0) {
    $("#firstgroup").prop('checked','');
    $(".order:checked").each(function(i, d) {
      selectedItems += d.id + ',';
    });
    $('#result').text('Checked Checkboxes: ' + selectedItems.substring(0, selectedItems.length - 1));
    $('#form').text('Total number of checked checkboxes: ' + $(".order:checked").length);
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="firstgroup" /> Select All<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="first" /> A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="second" /> B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="third" /> C
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="form"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dear Kapila, this work seamlessly, thank you very much.

Comment: Dear Kapila, to improve this a step further, what do we need to change to achieve this: After we check all the options manually, and then uncheck any of them, the Select All option should be also unchecked. How can we do this? Any idea?

Comment: I'm glad that it help you. When unchecked any of the check box you need to set $("#firstgroup").prop('checked',''); in the code. Please find the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue

```
$("#firstgroup").click(function() {
  var checkBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox'].order");
  checkBoxes.prop("checked", $("#firstgroup").prop("checked"));
});
```

The second issue I can not fix.

Comment: For the first time, after we check the option A then check the firstgroup checkbox, the info divs do not say that all the checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
<input type="checkbox" id="firstgroup" /> Select All<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="order" id="first" /> A<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="order" id="second" /> B<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="order" id="third" /> C
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="form">Lorem ipsum</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    x = document.getElementById("result");
    y = document.getElementById("form");
    x.innerHTML = '';
    y.innerHTML = '';

$("#firstgroup").click(function() {
    var checkBoxes = $("input[type='checkbox'].order");
    checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));
    $('.order').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);  //it will check and uncheck all checkbox
});


$("input[type='checkbox'].order").change(function() {
    var check       = $("input[type='checkbox'].order:checked").length;
var tnocb = $("input[type='checkbox'].order").length;
    var classes = $("input[type='checkbox'].order:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(", ");

if(check > 0) {
    if(check == 1) {
        x.innerHTML = 'Checked Checkbox: ' + classes + '<br>Total number of checked checkbox: ' + check;
    } else if(check == tnocb) {
        x.innerHTML = 'all of them are checked';
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = 'Checked Checkboxes: ' + classes + '<br>Total number of checked checkboxes: ' + check;
    }
    y.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = '';
        y.style.display = 'none';
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to leave a comment about what you've done and how it helps the op

Comment: Dear Chandrika, thank you for your reply. When I try your code I see a piece of text like "  });//]]>  " above the "Select All" checkbox!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#firstgroup").click(function () {
    if ($("#firstgroup[type='checkbox']:checked"));
    {
        $("#firstgroup").siblings("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the multiple checkboxes with Select All's code: http://jsfiddle.net/LUtJF/42/

Now, you can

1. Get the number of checked checkboxes
2. Get the labels of the checked checkboxes
3. Get a message when all the checkboxes are checked
4. When you select all the checkboxes, the "Select All" checkbox is also checked automatically, or vice versa.
5. The system is responsive. Whenever you add a new option, no need to change any code.

Thanks for all your contribution and hope you'll find this last version useful.
Ahmet Arduc
[www.ahmath.com](http://www.ahmath.com)

```
<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="firstgroup" /> Select All<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="first" /> A<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="second" /> B<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="third" /> C<br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="order" id="forth" /> D
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="form"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

$("#firstgroup").click(function() {
  $('#form').text('');
  $('#result').text('');
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  if($(".order:checked").length == $(".order").length) {
        $('#form').text('all of them are checked');
  }
});
$(".order").on('click', function() {
  var selectedItems = '';
  $('#result').text('');
  $('#form').text('');
  if ($(".order:checked").length == $(".order").length) {
    $('#firstgroup').prop('checked', true);
    $('#form').text('all of them are checked');
  } else if ($(".order:checked").length > 0) {
    $('#firstgroup').prop('checked', false);
    $(".order:checked").each(function(i, d) {
      selectedItems += d.id + ',';
    });
    $('#result').text('Checked Checkboxes: ' + selectedItems.substring(0, selectedItems.length - 1));
    $('#form').text('Total number of checked checkboxes: ' + $(".order:checked").length);
  }
});
```